# Closing Jena QueryEngineHTTP without closing the ResultSet

Tags: java, resultset, jena

I am using Apache Jena 2.12.0 to query a SPARQL endpoint. I want to close my QueryEngineHTTP object after usage but the following code will result in an unusable ResultSet, as it gets closed along with the QueryEngineHTTP. Is there a way to close one, but not the other?

```
public ResultSet select(String query)
{
    try(QueryEngineHTTP qe = new QueryEngineHTTP(ENDPOINT, query))
 {
        return qe.execSelect();
 } catch(Exception e) {throw new RuntimeException("Error on query:\n"+query,e);}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to detach the results from the incoming stream, you need to create a result set not driven by the incoming data - i.e. take a copy.

`ResultSetFactory.copyResults` will do that for you.  This result set is rewindable.

Comment: I was looking for this for so long, thanks this saved my day. Also here is the link to the documentation https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/app_api.html#passing-a-result-set-out-of-the-processing-loop